# How to process and change output before it is sent back to the browser?

Tags: cakephp

I want to implement a mechanism in CakePHP that is like ShortCodes in Wordpress. I want to save my pages (in the DB) with tokens, e.g.

```
[form id=12]
```

and then, after the view got rendered and before it is sent back to the browser, I want to search the rendered view for these tokens, and replace them with something else.

I assume I'll have to use `beforeFilter`, `afterFilter` or `beforeRender`, but I can't find any documentation (including in CakePHP's own documentation!) about how these overriden functions can be used to change the output.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The short "answer" is to use a different view class, that implements what you want. CakePHP doesn't work like you've described, so it's not much of a surprise for there to be no docs on it. Look at something similar to what you are wanting to do such as [TwigView](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView) or [BakeView](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/master/src/View/BakeView.php).

Comment: Wonderful! So if I understand correctly, I need to create a custom view; Set the viewClass in the controller; Override the render() function in the view; Call the parent's render function first, then search, replace and return? I'll try that in a few minutes. THANKS!!!